# CSS column-count and Chrome bug: how to avoid overflow content being cropped

Tags: html, css, column-count

When `column-count` is used, it seems to crop any **overflow** content.

```css
#columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  /*-webkit-column-fill: auto;*/
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  /*-moz-column-fill: auto;*/
  column-count: 1;
  column-gap: 10px;
  /*column-fill: auto;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}
.pin {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="columns">

  <div class="pin">

    <a href="#">
      <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
      <img src="#.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h3>Product 1</h3>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

**EDIT 1:**

It seems it is a **bug** in **Chrome**.

it is fine on Firefox though:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

```
span.onsale {
    min-height: 3.236em;
    min-width: 3.236em;
    padding: .202em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3.236;
    top: -.5em;
    left: -.5em;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: $highlight;
    color: $highlightext;
    font-size: .857em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm not sure how you are styling your `.onsale`  so I styled on my own way.</strike>

If you use `position:relative` in `.pin` and then `position:absolute` you can achieve what you want.

**UPDATE:** The issue is the `webkit-column-count:1` in Chrome and since having that with `1` or nothing is the same, just remove it and use another technique that will allow you to have the `.onsale` out of flow by using `position:absolute`

```css
#columns {
 
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}
.pin {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative
}
.onsale {
   min-height: 3.236em;
    min-width: 3.236em;
    padding: .202em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3.236;
    top: -.5em;
    left: -.5em;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: white;
    font-size: .857em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<div id="columns">
  <div class="pin">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
      <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
    </a>
    <h3>Product 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
      <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
    </a>
    <h3>Product 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. it looks like it is working here. but it still does not work on my chrome. I edited my question above to add the code of .onsale. it is from woocommerse for wordpress.

Comment: updated with your `onsale` code and works fone FF and Chrome

Comment: @teelou Forgot to mention you have an extra `</a>` after your `<h3>`, could be that

Comment: thanks for the edit. can you try to add another item of pin. `.onsale` does not show on the second `.pin`.

Comment: the extra a tag is my mistake.

Comment: Updated answer, take a look

Comment: so now can you see that `.onsale` items are being cropped? i think it is  a bug in chrome.

Comment: try run your code in firefox then you see what a mean.

Comment: so the solution is not to use `column-count`?

Comment: At least is a quick fix/hack that I found, since that's the issue in Chrome.

Answer (score 11):

Add `transform: translateZ(0);` to your `.pin` to enable hardware acceleration as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I have a fix for this too.

This example shows the use of

`transform: translateZ(0);`

which fixes the cropping issue. It also shows a clever way to show the content Above the other columns blocks using z-index on hover:

https://codepen.io/HaloDesign/pen/zdRoYZ

Answer (score 0):

Just use padding inside #columns class

Comment: where did you declare products class?